# Is there infinite number of postive integer pairs $(p>q)$ ,such $3(2^p+1)=(2^q+1)^2$

Tags: number-theory

Is there infinite number of  postive integer pairs $(p>q)$
$$3(2^p+1)=(2^q+1)^2$$

I add my some approach 
$$3\cdot 2^p+3=4^q+2^{q+1}+1$$
Give by
$$2^{2q-1}+2^q=3\cdot 2^{p-1}+1$$ I don't see how to proceed from this point

Comment: Please tell your efforts and reference for your problem? Is it homework?

Comment: My teacher give me  homework,

Comment: There are only finitely many of them. Observe the asymptotic behavior of them.

Comment: You do realise posting your HW without showing any efforts is wrong.... Plz edit what have you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given that $q \geq 1$ and $p>q$. From the last line of your attempt we have
$$2^{2q-1}+2^q=3\cdot 2^{p-1}+1$$
which can be rewritten as
$$2^{2q-1}+2^q-3\cdot 2^{p-1}=1$$
From the inequalities about $p,q$ we know that $2^{2q-1}$ and $2^{2q}$ are both even. Same goes for $2^{p-1}$ (because $p \geq 2$). Thus the left side is always even, whereas the right side is $1$ (odd).So.....

Answer (score 0):

Look at the binary digits of both sides.

Or consider the remainders $\bmod 4$

Comment: can you explain more detail,Thank you very much